# Use SinonJS to stub and spy on the same function?

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

In the following example, I want to [stub](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) the `get` function to prevent the actual HTTP request from occurring.  I want to [spy on](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) the `get` method to check what arguments it was called with.

```
var request = require('request'), sinon = require('sinon');
describe('my-lib', function() {
  sinon.stub(request, 'get').yield(null, null, "{}");
  var spy = sinon.spy(request, 'get');
  it('should GET some data', function(done) {
    function_under_test(function(err, response) {
      if(error) return done(error);
      assert(request.get.called);
      assert(request.get.calledWith('some', 'expected', 'args'));
    });
  });
});
```

Sinon does not seem to allow spying and stubbing the same method, though.  The above example gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap get which is already wrapped
```

---

How do I spy on a method, while preventing default behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the anonymous downvote!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The stub supports all the methods of a spy.  Just don't create the spy.

Comment: Wonderful man, thank you.  From the docs: `They support the full test spy API in addition to methods which can be used to alter the stub’s behavior.`